# echo HTML with php variable

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display the following and I have a css code for it but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML/PHP

```
 $var = "Hello World";
    echo '<p>' . 'the value of the variable is : ' . $var . '</p>';
```

CSS

```
p
{
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So, what do you see on the page?

Comment: @u_mulder **the value of the variable is : Hello World** but in black and aligned to left ( Note what I see is not in bold, I just did it in this comment )

Comment: Check with developer tools what styles are applied.

Comment: Then the PHP works, how do you add the CSS? btw, instead of echoing html you could stop php execution and echo php variables inside html instead. ie `$var = "Hello World"; ?> <p>the value of the variable is : <?= $var ?></p>`

Comment: How did you implement your CSS into your Page?

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks, it turned out that I forgot to insert it.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, I forgot to insert it. Such a dumb move. Sorry again.

Comment: Delete the question then

Comment: @u_mulder I tried, it doesn't allow me. It says that people have invested time and effort answering it !!

Comment: don't delete it.. millions of people will have the same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. run in your php enviroment

```
<html>
    <head>
         <style type="text/css">
           p
           {
              text-align: center;
              color: red;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
      $var = "Hello World";
      echo "<p>The value of the variable is : " . $var . "</p>";
    ?>
    </body>    

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
<?php 
$var = "Hello World";
echo "<p>The value of the variable is : " . $var . "</p>";
?>
```

Or like below in your HTML code where you want the php variable

```
<p>The value of the variable is : <?php echo $var;?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me in localhost.

```
  <?php
    $var = "Hello World";
        echo '<p>' . 'the value of the variable is : ' . $var . '</p>';
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    p
    {
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
```